# how do i set data based on the response data in RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

i'm new to RTK Query. in the docs, i found `transformResponse`, but no idea how to use it to solve this.

so my endpoint looks like this.

```
    getTransactions: build.query<TransactionResponse, void>({
      query: () => ({ url: 'transactions' }),
      providesTags: (result = []) => [
        ...result.map(
          ({ id }) => ({ type: 'Transaction', id } as const)
        ),
        { type: 'Transaction' as const, id: 'LIST' },
      ],
    }),
```

and every transaction data has a result data, which includes `is_error:boolean`.

after fetching transactions, i want to be able to count the number of `is_error`, and set it into TransactionResponse as `is_error_count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with transformResponse:

this is the response type:

```
type TransactionResponse = {
  transactions: Transaction[];
  is_error_count: number;
};
```

And this is the `transformResponse`:

```
      transformResponse: (response: Transaction[]) => {
        return {
          transactions: response,
          is_error_count: getIs_error_count(
            response.map((res) => res.transaction_result)
          ),
        };
      },
```

`getIs_error_count` is just a counter function, so just ignore it